# Nodejs/Express with Angular - 404 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I've been trying to learn the MEAN stack and wanted to do an application to test it out. The aim was to have a static variable (in this case 'hello') displayed by Angular in the HTML, I can't seem to get my $scope variable in my controller to display, having looked in the developer console on my browser I saw 'GET 127.0.0.1:3000/app.js 404 not found'.

This is my node server using express:

```
var express = require('express');
app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){

        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});



app.listen(3000, function() {
        console.log('I\'m listening on port 3000...');
});
```

This is my index.html file (a directory below in /views):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/
 angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Sucess!</h1>

        <div ng-controller="myController">
                <p>Angular test: {{ message }}</p>
        </div>
</body>
```

And this is my app.js file containing my module and controller (also in /views):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myModule', []);

    myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope',
function($scope) {

    $scope.message = 'hello';

}]);
```

I'd be very grateful if anyone could help out!

Comment: How do you expect that first script tag to work?

Comment: Have you tried to define static files folder https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html ?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The code was copied from nano on Ubuntu, the remainder of the script tag is: $/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: You may wish to [edit] your question to fix the code. Also, the DOCTYPE is missing the opening angle bracket.

Comment: @KostyaShkryob Thanks very much thats worked for me!

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Will do - Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to serve all the files, for example using [`express.static`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static), not just `index.html`:

```
var express = require('express');
app = express();

app.use(express.static('views'));

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('I\'m listening on port 3000...');
});
```

Comment: This works pretty fine, since angular & react are simple applications how can we solve 404 issue on page refresh?